# Clicking a button without ID in html

Tags: c#

Im using WebBrowser component to do all my things. Usually I press buttons using this:

```
browser.Document.GetElementById("11111111").InvokeMember("click");
```

But i dont know how to press a button that has no id on the html code. Can i get all the items and thieir id or something?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use other methods of `document`, like `GetElementsByClassName` (note that this returns a nodelist rather than a single node).

Maybe you can have a look at this: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html

Or if that is too dry, have a look at the [IHTMLDocument2 interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which is the interface that describes which properties and methods you have available on the `document` object. Which exactly you need depends on the structure of your HTML. Iterating over all elements is possible, but usually (and hopefully) there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

If the button you're after is part of a form, and you happen to know its index, then you can grab all the elements by their tag name, which is this case would be "input", and index along them:

```
int n = 3   // this would be the index of the input element you want

browser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")[n].InvokeMember("click");
```